# Return reference to private member

Tags: c++, reference

I have a class

```
class SomeClass {
  public:
    using DType = std::vector<int>;

    DType& data1() {   // this should return a reference to data
      return data;
    }

    DType data2() {   // this should return a copy to data
      return data;
    }

  private:
    DType data;
}
```

My understanding is, if I do

```
SomeClass temp;
auto d1 = temp.data1();  // this should NOT do any copying just create a new ref
auto d2 = temp.data2();  // this supposed to copy the data?
```

I am reading a book and it says when I do

```
auto d1 = temp.data1()
```

It will make a copy of the whole data and assign to d1... Does the book make any mistake?

*
*
*
************ updated from reading other's answer *****************

It seems "auto" is doing something funny here. I guess if I do:

```
std::vector<int>& d1 = temp.data1() . // this is not copying
```

But if I do:

```
std::vector<int> d1 = temp.data1() . // this is copying
```

Comment: As a sidenote: you should not return handles (references, pointers, iterators) to object internals (data members) as it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: If the book doesn't mention that `auto` never infers a reference type, it's a mistake.

Comment: The mistake here is to return a non-`const` reference and break encapsulation.

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding is incorrect. `auto d1 = temp.data1();` will make a copy. If you want a reference, use `auto& d1 = temp.data1();`.

Comment: Thanks! I kinda of feel that. When should I use "auto&" and when should I use "auto"?

Comment: I guess if I don't use auto it will be cleaner

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld If you want a copy by value, use `auto`. If you want a reference, use `auto&`.